# Items Don't Display in Android Studio Blueprint or Design

Tags: android, android-studio

so I'm trying out Android Studio for the first time, and I've already run into something. I'm following the official "first application" tutorial on developer.android.com, but it's not matching up. So, I tested this with two apps, and it wasn't like a bug in the first one exclusively, it happened in both. Here's a pic of an app where nothing has been changed and I followed the tutorial exactly:

[image: Example photo]

As you can see in the hierarchy, it is supposed to have the Hello World text that displays when you make a new app. However, with me not changing anything, it's not showing up.

Any ideas?

**Also to clarify, the items do show up when I run it on my device, it just doesn't show up on the computer.**

Comment: This is probably an issue with rendering Layout preview

Comment: add gradle dependency

Answer (score 2):

Check the upper right corner of the Preview screen, you should see a red warning mark. Click on that and it will tell what is preventing Android Studio from rendering your layout.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. It leads to the solution for a variety or causes.

Answer (score 0):

Some times android studio stuck or something.Try doing

> File->Invalidate Caches/Restart

Answer (score 0):

In your style.xml file change the string parent with the below line:

```
 parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is

1. `Clean` Project
2. `Rebuild` Project